# Tikz hexagon with arrows and key

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I construct the following hexagon in tikz?

[image]

For now I tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\foreach \l [count=\n] in {text,text,text,text,text,text}
{\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{90-360/6*(\n-1)}
\node[label={\angle:\l}] (n\n) at (\angle:1) {};}
\draw[dashed] (n2) -- (n4) -- (n6) -- (n2);
\draw[dotted] (n1) -- (n3) -- (n5) -- (n1);
\draw[->] (n2) -- (n1);
\draw[->] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[->] (n4) -- (n3);
\draw[->] (n4) -- (n5);
\draw[->] (n6) -- (n5);
\draw[->] (n6) -- (n1);
\draw[>-<] (n1) -- (n4);
\draw[>-<] (n2) -- (n5);
\draw[>-<] (n3) -- (n6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Whar you try so far? Heksagon you can draw by use of `regular polygon` shape from `shapes.geometric` library.

Comment: I used `\foreach \x/\l/\p in { 30/{(text}/above, 90/{text}/above, 150/{text}/left, 210/{text}/below, 270/{text}/below, 330/{text}/right}` but I don't know how i can draw the arrows or how to position the text according to the picture.

Comment: Please ad this code to your question. For drawing arrows you need to name a coordinates of polygon corners.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that. How can I name the polygon coordinates?

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way... but it works:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    implikation/.style={stealth-stealth, thick},
    disjunktion/.style={dotted},
    exklusion/.style={dashed},
    kontravalenz/.style={>-<, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
]
    \foreach[count=\i from 1] \txt/\pos in {%
        verboten/right,%
        pflichtig/above,%
        geboten/left,%
        {(relativ)\\erlaubt}/left,%
        {indifferent\\(absolut) erlaubt}/below,%
        {ungeboten\\(freigestellt)}/right%
    }{
        \coordinate[label={[align=center]\pos:\txt}] (node-\i) at ({60*\i-30}:2.5cm) {};
    }

    \draw[exklusion] (node-1) -- (node-3) -- (node-5) -- (node-1);
    \draw[disjunktion] (node-2) -- (node-4) -- (node-6) -- (node-2);

    \foreach \from/\to in {1/4, 2/5, 3/6}{
        \draw[kontravalenz] (node-\from) -- (node-\to);
    }

    \foreach \i/\j/\k in {6/1/2, 2/3/4, 4/5/6}{
        \draw[implikation] (node-\i) -- (node-\j) -- (node-\k);
    }

    \begin{scope}[shift={(-3,-4)}]
        \foreach \xpos/\ypos/\name/\style in {%
            0/0/Implikation/implikation,%
            3.5/0/Disjunktion/disjunktion,%
            0/-0.5/Exklusion/exklusion,%
            3.5/-0.5/Kontravalenz/kontravalenz%
        }{
            \draw[\style] (\xpos,\ypos) -- ++(0.8,0) node[right] {$=${} \name};
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How can I add a key as shown in the original picture?

Comment: @philipp_th please see my latest edit.

Comment: U can give the background ...

Comment: Thank you very much!